# How can I prevent Rollup.js from creating an empty chunk when building scss?

Tags: javascript, sass, bundling-and-minification, rollupjs

I'm trying to use rollup.js to bundle my SCSS. See my config file below. When it runs, it creates the appropriate css files but it also creates `screen.js` which is empty and gives me a warning in the console:

```
rollup v3.17.3
bundles src/scss/screen.scss → dist/css...
(!) Generated an empty chunk
"screen"
created dist/css in 1.3s
bundles src/js/cat.js → dist/js...
created dist/js in 1.2s
```

Is there a way to prevent it from creating this empty chunk?

```js
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import terser from '@rollup/plugin-terser';
import css from 'rollup-plugin-import-css';
import scss from 'rollup-plugin-scss';
import postcss from 'postcss';
import autoprefixer from 'autoprefixer';

const production = !process.env.ROLLUP_WATCH;

export default [
    {
        input: 'src/scss/screen.scss',
        output: {dir:'dist/css'},
        plugins: [
            scss({
                fileName: 'css.css',
                sourceMap: true,
                processor: () => postcss([autoprefixer()])
            })
        ]
    },
    {
        input: 'src/js/cat.js',
        output: {
            dir: 'dist/js',
            format: 'es',
            sourcemap: true,
            chunkFileNames: '[name].js'
        },
        plugins: [
            css(),
            resolve(),
            production && terser(),
        ]
    }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a plugin to delete empty js files

```js
const Input = [path.resolve(CWD, `${ROOT_DIR}/**/*.less`)];
function buildLess() {
  rollup({
    input: Input,
    plugins: [
      multiInput({
        relative: ROOT_DIR,
      }),
      styles({
        mode: 'extract',
        plugins: postcssPlugins,
      }),
      { // start
        generateBundle: (option, bundle) => {
          Object.keys(bundle).forEach(key => {
            if (bundle[key].type !== 'asset') {
              delete bundle[key];
            }
          });
        },
      }, // end
    ],
  }).then(reactBundle => {
    reactBundle.write({
      dir: 'es',
      assetFileNames: '[name].css',
    });
  });
}
```